# Django - allow anonymous API usage on localhost

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I'm making an Ajax call in the UI to the API, so the localhost needs to be able to query the API. Users of the platform should be able to access the API, but need to use a token I already provide.

Is there a way to allow anonymous API usage locally only?

I looked into JWT and it does not seem to be the right fit.

Comment: So actually you want an authentication header in your requests or something along the lines? What do you mean by 'locally only'?

Comment: Why not using a token for local access as well?

Comment: Why not using a token for local access as well?

Comment: i didn't understand what "anonymous api usage" means

Comment: @KlausD. If I used a token within the UI, it will be exposed to anyone that views the source code of the page. They would then be able to use the token that my UI/frontend is using.

Comment: @AsifMohammed Anonymous meaning not using a token.

Comment: @MilanVelebit it's hosted in AWS' Elastic Beanstalk, and developed on my laptop. Wherever the app is being hosted, I'd like for the UI to be able to call the API.

Comment: @J.BrettCunningham I'd say look into CORS and how to set it up (I don't remember whether it's enabled by default while declaring Django endpoints, if it's already setup then you're fine), just out of curiosity, why do you think JSON is not the right fit for this case, seems like a perfect fit in this case, it's a well-established authorization system, you don't have to mingle much to set it up.

Comment: @MilanVelebit With JWT, the private token would still be passed publicly through the user's browser.

Comment: @J.BrettCunningham Well every token that you send is accessible at at one way or another, right? JWT exposes its data but can be verified whether's it's valid or not because one part is hashed using a `secret key` at serverside. If you really don't want anything exposable at clientside, you can set up your server to act as a proxy itself and make the server send requests, or rather 'pass' them.

Comment: @MilanVelebit I was over- or under-thinking it. You're exactly right. I'd like to mark your comment as the solution, but I think you need to make it an answer.

Comment: @J.BrettCunningham Added the answer, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've pointed out in the comments, [JWTs](https://jwt.io/) should suffice in this case as, from what I've understood, you're not handling any extremely sensitive data (which can be hashed and not exposable to the user using JWTs as well) but want to validate each request. Using the same link you can check the validity of a token in their debugger.